# combining two list of bits into one and then converting it to hex

Tags: python-3.x

I have two 'bit' lists:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
b = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

what I want is an element wise representation of these two lists eg.:

```
c = 0b11101111010111
```

and finally what i am after is to convert this var "c" to a hex representation eg.,
h = 0x3BD7

What I have in mind is to simply loop element wise and con cat these two list (a & b) in to C but that seems silly especially in python i am wondering if there are any other "smarter/faster" ways to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `zip` to combine the two lists, then `chain` to flatten that result and finally `BitArray` and its `uint` method to interpret that as a series of bits:

```
from itertools import chain
from bitstring import BitArray

a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
b = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
num = BitArray(chain(*zip(a, b))).uint
print(hex(num)) # 0x3bd7
```

Comment: thx for you comment, 
but I think your suggestion combine these two list, i., adding list "b" after list "a" and then converts it to hex, thats why you get 0x3cdf and not 0x3bd7 which i expect

Comment: I completely rewrote my answer in light of that.